# Error on installation of apache2 and php5

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, apache2, dependencies

This error occurs when I install the `apache2` & `php5` around the time that `libapace2-mod-php5` is installed:

```
root@ubuntuServerASC:/home/asc# apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cron : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2)
        Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libpam-runtime (>= 1.0.1-11) but it is not going to be installed
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ucf but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
 libpam-modules : PreDepends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                              debconf-2.0
                  PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2)
                  Recommends: update-motd but it is not going to be installed
 libpam0g : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                     debconf-2.0
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried use `apt-cache` to resolve the dependency but it didn't work.

```
root@ubuntuServerASC:/home/asc# apt-cache depends libapache2-mod-php5
libapache2-mod-php5
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libdb5.3
  Depends: libpcre3
  Depends: libssl1.0.0
  Depends: libxml2
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: <apache2-api-20120211>
    apache2-bin
  Depends: apache2
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: php5-common
  Depends: libmagic1
  Depends: ucf
  Depends: tzdata
  Conflicts: <libapache2-mod-php4>
  Conflicts: libapache2-mod-php5filter
  Recommends: php5-cli
  Suggests: php-pear
```

I installed all of the required packages.

I'm running ubuntu 16 LTS server.